# Filter critieria for Data field?

Tags: reporting

I am making a report which should show me the optys whose last activities is not in the last 30 days and also show me the optys whose stage has been modified to Not interesed in the last 14 days

3. Stage equals New Enquiry,Contacted,Qualified,Appointment,Future Stages
4. Last Activity Date less than 30 DAYS AGO
5. Stage equals Not Interested
6. Last Activity Date equals LAST 14 DAYS

Regards,
A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to create a custom date field called "Last Not Interested Date" and create a workflow that will update that field whenever the opportunity is set to "not interested".  Then you can create a filter in your report on "Last Note Interested Date" equals LAST 14 DAYS.

-1 and 2 and NOT 3

1. Stage equals New Enquiry,Contacted,Qualified,Appointment,Future Stages
2. Last Activity Date less than 30 DAYS AGO
3. Last Not Interested Date equals LAST 14 DAYS

Comment: Thanks Thomas, Yours reply does suit my requirements. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Filter Logic: 1 OR (2 AND 3)

1. Last Activity greater than "30 days ago"
2. Stage Duration less or equal "14"
3. Stage equals "Not interesed"

Drop the filter logic if all criteria has to apply to any opportunity returned by report